# I need help to figure out syntax for a view in an existing PostgreSQL database that extracts (unnests) content in a JSON array field

Tags: json, postgresql

I am working on a JSON array field named **session_durations** in existing PostgreSQL 11.8 database view. Each field describes the sessionID and the duration (amount of time a program user visits that session). There are 12 possible sessions, an "session" refers here to online lesson in an eHealth treatment program.

This JSON field (session_durations) is populated as the user accesses the session. If user never accesses a session then no data appears in the JSON field for that session (see my examples) -- hence some sessions can be skipped over entirely.

I'd like to use SQL code to unpack this field in order to separate its components. Here are 2 example records:

Record 1: `[{"sessionId":"7","duration":1886400},{"sessionId":"8","duration":1710000},{"sessionId":"9","duration":706800}]`

Record 2: `[{"sessionId":"1","duration":879600},{"sessionId":"2","duration":975600},{"sessionId":"3","duration":9600}]`

I'd like to use my View to save duration data (e.g., "duration":879600) from each possible session into 12 new columns for each user session (e.g., "sessionId":"1") named the following:

•   S1_duration
•   S2_duration
•   S3_duration
•   S4_duration
•   S5_duration
•   S6_duration...
•   S12_duration

All help would be greatly appreciated!!

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int4 PRIMARY KEY,
  session_durations json
);
```

**----some rows of data:**

```
13  [{"sessionId":"1","duration":12699},{"sessionId":"7","duration":1423041},{"sessionId":"8","duration":7598502},{"sessionId":"10","duration":1531229}]
14  [{"sessionId":"1","duration":55812},{"sessionId":"7","duration":2905}]
161 [{"sessionId":"7","duration":1125600},{"sessionId":"8","duration":460800}]
12  [{"sessionId":"1","duration":1520988},{"sessionId":"2","duration":94565},{"sessionId":"6","duration":35468}]
```

---

Your solutions worked perfectly! I chose to use the second solution (grouping syntax) for my project. Thanks for your patience -- and the online demo examples!

Comment: That's a little unclear. Which value is supposed to go in which column? And what if you had 4 rows in the table instead of 2, what would the result look like?

Comment: 12 columns, really? Why not normalise that schema?

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
WITH usd AS (
  SELECT
    us.id AS user_id,
    (sd->>'sessionId')::int AS session_id,
    (sd->>'duration')::int AS duration
  FROM users us,
  LATERAL json_array_elements(us.session_durations) AS sd
)
SELECT
  users.id AS user_id,
  (SELECT duration FROM usd WHERE user_id = users.id AND session_id = 1) AS "S1_duration",
  (SELECT duration FROM usd WHERE user_id = users.id AND session_id = 2) AS "S2_duration",
  (SELECT duration FROM usd WHERE user_id = users.id AND session_id = 3) AS "S3_duration",
  …
  (SELECT duration FROM usd WHERE user_id = users.id AND session_id = 12) AS "S12_duration"
FROM users;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=75286dea8a40a91724184daf23f45a9c))</sup>

Alternatively, using grouping and some filtered aggregate (dealing better with potential duplicates):

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  MAX(duration) FILTER (WHERE session_id = 1) AS "S1_duration",
  MAX(duration) FILTER (WHERE session_id = 2) AS "S2_duration",
  MAX(duration) FILTER (WHERE session_id = 3) AS "S3_duration",
  …
  MAX(duration) FILTER (WHERE session_id = 12) AS "S12_duration"
FROM (
  SELECT
    us.id AS user_id,
    (sd->>'sessionId')::int AS session_id,
    (sd->>'duration')::int AS duration
  FROM users us,
  LATERAL json_array_elements(us.session_durations) AS sd
) AS usd
GROUP BY user_id;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0852aa81d583abcf093e7f71b5a27696))</sup>

Comment: The field is JSON not JSONB -- maybe reason I get error regarding LATERAL?

Comment: I was able to use following to create multiple records for each program user with session durations data!

Comment: But not yet able to use your second SELECT to select AS 12 separate fields -- possible my problem with LATERAL?

Comment: This code created the multiple records per program user with sessionId and duration date:  
SELECT us.id,
    json_array_elements(us.session_durations) ->> 'sessionId'::text AS session_id,
    (json_array_elements(us.session_durations) ->> 'duration'::text)::integer AS duration
   FROM users us

Comment: Are you getting an error, or just not the desired result? Please share your table definitions and some rows of example data if you need further help.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64759707/edit) to include them

Comment: @BrianD Thanks, fixed. I was missing a comma before the `LATERAL`